# How to override 'lambda' in Python?

Tags: python

How can I redefine the syntax level `lambda` operator in python?

For example, I want to be able to do this:

```
λ = lambda
squared = λ x: x*x
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to make a mathematical looking python just for aesthetical reasons. I like this Vim plugin: https://github.com/ehamberg/vim-cute-python, but wanted to see if I could take it further.

Comment: You can do this in your text-editor, but not in Python itself because it is a keyword.

Comment: If you are using emacs, you can use `pretty-lambda-mode`

Comment: the feature in vim hides it for the user, but the file is always the same.

Comment: And there is one for sublime too...

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I already use a Vim plugin which superficially changes this. I want to change the language itself though.

Comment: @therealtypon Change the basic grammar as per the instructions given here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html For example currently it's possible to assign keywords like True, False, None in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

As some other users have noted, `lambda` is a reserved keyword in Python, and so cannot be aliased or overridden in the same way that you would a function or variable without changing the grammar of the Python language. However, you can define a function which itself defines and returns a new lambda function from a string expression using the `exec` keyword. This changes the styling somewhat, but the top level behavior is similar.

That is:

```
def λ(expression):

    local_dictionary = locals()

    exec("new_lambda = lambda %s" % (expression), globals(), local_dictionary)

    return local_dictionary["new_lambda"]

# Returns the square of x.
y = λ("x : x ** 2") 

# Prints 2 ^ 2 = 4.
print(y(2))
```

Which is comparable to:

```
# Returns the square of x.
y = lambda x : x ** 2 

# Prints 2 ^ 2 = 4.
print(y(2))
```